# Gulp throwing "is read-only while parsing file" error while running Gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to create ES6 module in JavaScript and I get error like: `Line 20: "NotFound" is read-only while parsing file`.

The `NotFound` is the name of my module.

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';

const NotFound = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <h1>Not Found!</h1>
        );
    }
});

export default NotFound;
```

I'm importing it the following way: `import NotFound from './components/NotFound';`
How to solve this issue? Changing file rights to 777 doesn't help at all (I know it's incorrect, but I was trying to find a solution).

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it looks like I had defined a variable before calling import. The variable name was exactly the same as the imported module name. That was the root of the issue.