# How to import PaperJS from node modules?

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, paperjs

I installed Paper JS via NPM
the "paper" folder is well in my Node_Modules folder
i try to import paper with

```
import paper from 'paper';
```

and then, gulp throw me

"  "paper" is read-only while parsing file  "

Never faced such error... 
Someone has an idea about how to deal with it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958150/gulp-throwing-is-read-only-while-parsing-file-error-while-running-gulp-task

Comment: Please include the stack trace

Comment: Can you provide the whole gulpfile.js code ?